# Como editar solo algunos articulos traidos de SQL con PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tengo un sistema que hace cotizaciones, los precios de los productos los he dejado de solo lectura (no editables en su precio) sin embargo me piden que ciertos artículos que vienen en esa lista si los puedan editar.
Todos los datos los extraigo con una consulta de MySQL.
Hay algún método de hacer solo ciertos productos editables y los demás sigan sin tener una casilla de editar?

Quiero saber si mi variable $precio_venta=$row["precio_siva"];

y
$precio_iva=$row["precio_iva"]; puede ser editable pero solo en ciertos id's, y no en todos los campos que aparezcan. Como ven, tengo el input en readonly, por lo cual no son editables

```
          <table class="table">
            <tr  class="warning">
                <th>C&oacute;digo</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th><span class="pull-right">Cant.</span></th>
                <th><span class="pull-right">Descuento</span></th>
                <th><span class="pull-right">Precio</span></th>


                <th style="width: 36px;"></th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $id_producto=$row['id'];
                $codigo_producto=$row['codigo_producto'];
                $nombre_producto=$row['nombre_producto'];
                $codigo_producto=$row["codigo_producto"];
                $precio_venta=$row["precio_siva"];
                $precio_iva=$row["precio_iva"];




                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><? echo $codigo_producto; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $nombre_producto; ?></td>
                    <td class='col-xs-1'>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="cantidad_<? echo $id_producto; ?>"  value="1" >
                    </div></td>

                    <td class='col-xs-1'>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="descuento_<? echo $id_producto; ?>" value="0.0">
                    </div></td>


                    <td class='col-xs-2'><div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" readonly="readonly" id="precio_venta_<? echo $id_producto; ?>"  value="<? echo $precio_venta;?>" >
                    </div></td>
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" readonly="readonly" id="precio_iva_<? echo $id_producto; ?>"  value="<? echo $precio_iva;?>" >


                    <td ><span class="pull-right"><a href="#" onclick="agregar('<? echo $id_producto ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a></span></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=5><span class="pull-right"><?
                 echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);
                ?></span></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], a tu pregunta le hace falta mucha información; por ejemplo: filtras esa información directo de la base de datos?(así sería mas simple solo mostrar los que cumplan una condición y sean editables), en caso contrario deberás indicarnos que llevas hecho y mostrar el código mínimo necesario para hacer un ejemplo

Comment: cómo ya te han dicho faltan muchos datos. ¿Bajo qué criterio harias esa condición? No olvides dar un tour por el sitio para aprender a formular las preguntas con la información necesaria para ayudarte

Comment: Como dicen los compañeros la pregunta no se entiende. Puedes tener una variable dinámica que use un ternario para hacer la comparación y agregar esa variable a cada input. Por ejemplo: `$ro = ($campo1 == $campo2) ? "readonly" : "";`cuando `$campo1` sea igual a `$campo=2` la variable `$ro` tendrá el valor `readonly`, de lo contrario será una cadena vacía, luego en la construcción dinámica de los `input` **usas `$ro` en todos**. En aquellos donde la condición se cumpla se agregará `readonly`  y en los que no se agregará nada. El problema es que no se entiende la condición que debe cumplirse.